# Where to find custom persistent values in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, gtag.js

I am sending custom persistent values to Google analytics using `gtag` as per the following documentation

[image]

I am setting the custom value when I have the information available after an API call.

So on page load I do `gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID_1');`

and once I have the data from an API call I do `gtag('set', { tenantName: '<tenant_name_from_response>' });`

Now my question is where do I see this parameter country in my Google analytics report? Or do I need to do something special to see it?

My GA dashboard - [image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want to use is a session- or user-scoped custom dimension: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

Answer (score 1):

The code presented is not sending the information right now. 
The code is not mapping the Custom Dimension, the pageview script should look like this

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
  'custom_map': {'dimensionXX': 'tenantName'} //remplace the X for the correct index
});
```

The index is given to you when you create the custom dimension on the platform, on the Property Tab admin.